# Matrix Iteration - Which method is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, pixel

I'd like to know which of the below methods could be considered more efficient.
The first one is quite simple it uses two for loops. The last one is my personal favorite, because it only uses one. I'm not quite sure about the pros and cons of each method though, as they are both pretty fast.

They are meant to be used with a [CanvasPixelArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) or ones that are structured in a similar way.
`w` and `h` stands for the width and height of the 2d matrices.

```
for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {

        // ...
    }
}


for (var i = 0, l = w*h; i < l; i++) {

    var x = i%w;
    var y = Math.floor(i/w);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: [http://jsperf.com/nested-loop/2](http://jsperf.com/nested-loop/2) would give you some indication for that.

Comment: In either case the time taken doing simple arithmetic is likely to be dwarfed by that needed to perform drawing operations on the canvas. The 1st method has the other advantage of being easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first will be more efficient. Think about the number of operations you are doing in the first method: One single incrementation per pixel plus an additional incrementation per row. The other method saves the extra incrementation per row but replaces it with something far more complex. In addition to the rounding and the `%` which are expensive, the `y` value is recalculated each and every time, whereas it is only calculated once per row in method 1. In short, the extra incrementation per row will be far quicker than adding all these supplementary operations per pixel. This isn't to say that you shouldn't use the second method, but given the code you have posted the first will perform better.

Comment: Mh alright, thank you both. Although it hurts leaving my fancy single for loop I guess I'll go with the first one from now on.

Comment: Just re-edited... like I said it's not that you shouldn't use the second (maybe you are already performing these calculations elsewhere and can re-use the values, reducing the cost of the iteration) but if you are looking for performance the first should still perform a bit better.